# Sending mail with PHPMailer through proxy?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send an e-mail with PHPMailer through a SMTP proxy but am not able to find a field or function in PHPMailer to allow me to do this.

Maybe you can help me out? If PHPMailer doesn't have support for this maybe you can recommend me a free mailer program which does?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as an SMTP proxy - only port forwarders (sometimes refered to as Null mailers) and SMTP relays. It is possible to route arbitrary ports/protocols through HTTP and SOCKS proxies - but AFAIK that's not supported by any products out of the box.

For both port forwarders and SMTP relays, it's just a matter of telling phpmailer the host and port to use:

```
 ...
 $mua = new PHPMailer();
 ...
 $mua->Host = 'my-smtp-relay.example.com';
 $mua->Port = '2525';
 ...
 $mua->Send();
 ...
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure any outbound connect can be made through a proxy.