# Is it possible to use proxy when sending emails?

Tags: php, email

I am using phpmailer, but my server is some how blacklisted, maybe because of other bad sites. I know I can use proxy when using cURL;

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "88.65.120.46:80");
```

My question is, is it possible to use proxy when sending e-mails ?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291190/sending-mail-with-phpmailer-through-proxy

Comment: "somehow blacklisted" fix the disease not the symptom